# Trouble adding multiple images to CSS/JS modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a few images pop up individually in a modal. I can only seem to get the first image to pop up, but not the 2nd. I would prefer to make the images pop up in a modal that will let you switch between them, but I at least need them to pop up individually.

**Html:**

```
  <div class="container">
     <img id="myImg" src="images/300-200.png" alt="Filler Text" width="300" height="200">
     <img id="myImg2" src="images/300-200.png" alt="Filler Text" width="300" height="200">
     <div id="myModal" class="modal"> 
         <span class="closeimg" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
         <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
         <div id="caption"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

I know there is an issue since I can't use `.getElementByID` to pick up more than one ID and I know that two elements can't be labeled the same ID. With that being said, I have tried `.getElementByClassName` which didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to select multiple elements of the same kind you should use a class selector since it has the ability to appear multiple times on a page, where an id is unique to one element.

So, first we'll add `class="myImg"` to each of the two images.

```
<img id="myImg" class="myImg" src="images/300-200.png" alt="Filler Text" width="300" height="200">
<img id="myImg2" class="myImg" src="images/300-200.png" alt="Filler Text" width="300" height="200">
```

Then we'll change how we're selecting the images:

```
// From this
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
// To this
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
```

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns the array-like `HTMLCollection` type, you need to iterate through each element, then add the event listener to it.

```
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i = i + 1) {
    var img = imgs[i];
    img.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    };
};
```

---

Here's a working version of this example:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i = i + 1) {
 var img = imgs[i];
  img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  };
};

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeimg")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img id="myImg" class="myImg" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="Cat 1" width="300" height="200">
  <img id="myImg2" class="myImg" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Cat 1" width="300" height="200">
  
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="closeimg">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me out a lot! I am new to JS so I was not sure exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="images/300-200.png" alt="Filler Text" width="300" height="200">
    <img class="img" src="images/300-200.png" alt="Filler Text" width="300" height="200">

    <div id="myModal" class="modal"> 
        <span class="closeimg" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
        <img id="modal-img">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
</div>

var img = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
    modal = document.getElementById('myModal'),
    modal_img = document.getElementById('modal-img'),
    captionText = document.getElementById('caption');

[].forEach.call(img, function(element){
    element.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        modal_img.src = this.getAttribute('src');
        caption.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('alt');
    }
});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmdqjmua/

Try it.